# Is there necessary and sufficient condition on whether a symmetric circulant matrix is non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there necessary and sufficient condition on whether a symmetric circulant matrix is non-singular? I found many example supporting that positive symmetric circulant matrices which has at least two different entries are non-singular.

Comment: Clearly$$\pmatrix{a&b&a&b\cr b&a&b&a\cr a&b&a&b\cr b&a&b&a\cr}$$is singular.